# Hamiltonian system with velocity singularity

Tags: classical-mechanics, hamiltonian-formalism, singularities, non-linear-systems

I am studying a classical mechanical system for which Hamilton's equations are the following:

$$
\psi' = \frac{p}{\sqrt{1-p^2}},~~~~~p' = -\phi \sin \psi,
$$

where $\phi$ is a parameter. If $\phi>1/2$, then there are certain initial values of $p$ and $\psi$ that inevitably end up at one of the lines $p=1$ or $p=-1$, implying that the velocity $\psi'$ diverges. Specifically, if the initial conditions satisfy
$$
\psi \ge \cos^{-1}\left(1-\frac{1}{\phi}\right),~~~~~p = 0,
$$
we reach the $p=1$ line. Is there any way to understand these dynamics physically?

If I attempt to numerically integrate the equations of motion, the solver gives a solution for $\psi$ with a discontinuous jump at the singularity, with $\psi$ going from some value $-\psi_0$ to $\psi_0$. Is there any reason to believe this, i.e. to trust any result past the singularity? How can this system be understood when $\phi>1/2$?

Any help or suggested reading material is appreciated.

EDIT:
The full Lagrangian is given by

$$L = \sqrt{1+\psi'^2} + \phi \cos\psi.$$

This does indeed have a rigorous analogy to a relativistic pendulum.

Comment: Have you tried using an adaptive timestep to ensure that you never hop over the singularity?

Comment: Also, what is your Hamiltonian here? Looks like you're trying to describe what might be a relativistic point particle in a periodic potential, but in that case the denominator of your $\psi '$ equation should have a $+$ in it...
$$
H = m\sqrt{1+p^2/m^2}-V_0\cos x\\
\Rightarrow \ \dot x = \frac{\partial H}{\partial p}=\frac{p}{\sqrt{m^2+p^2}}, \ \dot p = -\frac{\partial H}{\partial x}=-V_0\sin x
$$

Comment: See my edit. I have not paid much attention to the time step issue. I'm mostly interested in understanding this system analytically.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.07662 analogy to relativistic pendulum

Comment: Cool paper. I mention timesteps because have you proved that there are initial conditions that end up with $|p|=1$, or are you saying that based on examining a few numerical solutions? I ran a quick adaptive timestep Monte Carlo of the system to see the flow in phase space, and after 10k initial conditions with $\phi = .1$ I have yet to have a solution blow up.

Comment: @DamianSowinski Ah, you're right, I messed up the inequality. It should be if $\phi>1/2$. I've added the details above.

Comment: I see the new edits. Are you absolutely sure that that is your Lagrangian, and not with a $-$ sign in the square root? I only mention this because if the sign were changed, then this Lagrangian would properly describe the a relativistic particle in a potential, and your $\phi$ problem would no longer exist. I'm not sure how to interpret the Lagrangian you have written down. It's Hamiltonian reads:
$$H =-\sqrt{1-p^2}-\phi\cos\psi$$ which gives the wrong relativistic energy-momentum relation.

Comment: This is actually a phenomenological model, not something derived from first principles, developed and applied here: http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/jacs.5b06800. So although I know it is strange, it is correct.

Comment: FWIW: the system is formally identical to Born-Infeld in $1+1$ dimensions in the axial gauge (plus a weird self-interaction term).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to understand the phenomenon just using energy conservation.

**N.B.** *I henceforth assume* $\phi \geq 0$.

Since the Lagrangian does not depend on time explicitly, the Hamiltonian is conserved along the solutions:
$$\sqrt{1-p(t)^2} + \phi \cos \psi(t) = \sqrt{1-p(0)^2} + \phi \cos \psi(0)\:.$$
The evolution of the system necessarily stays along a connected component of the curve above in the plane $\psi, p$, determined by the initial conditions.
To understand the dynamics  would be very helpful plotting the curves 
$$\sqrt{1-p^2} + \phi \cos \psi =E$$
for various values of $E$,  however I go on exploiting an analytic approach.

Suppose that a certain time the velocity of $\psi$ diverges, i.e.,  $p(t)=\pm 1$, thus 
$$ \phi \cos \psi(t) = \sqrt{1-p(0)^2} + \phi \cos \psi(0)\:.$$
If you also assume $p(0)=0$ as you wrote, you have
$$ \phi \cos \psi(t) = 1+\phi \cos \psi(0)\:.$$
Namely
$$\cos \psi(t) = \frac{1}{\phi} + \cos \psi(0)\:.$$
Since $|\cos \psi(t)|\leq 1$ and $|\cos \psi(0)|\leq 1$, this identity is possible only if $1/\phi \leq 2$ that is
$$\phi \leq \frac{1}{2}\:.\tag{1}$$
Assuming it, since $|\cos \psi(t)|\leq 1$ we have 
$$-1 -\frac{1}{\phi} \leq \cos \psi(0) \leq 1-\frac{1}{\phi}  \leq 1$$
The left hand side condition is always satisfied since $-1 -\frac{1}{\phi} < -1 \leq  \cos \psi(0) $. The other condition leads to 
$$ \cos \psi(0) \leq  1-\frac{1}{\phi} $$ which implies, dealing with $\psi(0) \in [0,2\pi]$ 
$$\pi -\cos^{-1}\left(1- \frac{1}{\phi}\right) \geq \psi(0) \geq \cos^{-1}\left(1- \frac{1}{\phi}\right)\:.\tag{2}$$
(1) and (2) are *necessary* conditions for  the existence of solutions with $p(0)=0$ such that $\psi'(t)$ diverges for some time $t$.

The fact that they also are sufficient  can only be proved through a closer scrutiny discussing when the point $(\psi(t),p(t))$ is allowed to stop along a connected component of the curve $$\sqrt{1-p(t)^2} + \phi \cos \psi(t) = \sqrt{1-p(0)^2} + \phi \cos \psi(0)\:.$$
Otherwise the point must moves along the complete connected component reaching 
the anomalous points with $p=\pm 1$ if they are allowed on the curve.
Stops along the curve are nothing but the zeros of the gradient of the Hamiltonian.

If $$\phi > \frac{1}{2}\:,$$
*energy conservation* prevents the system from admitting  pathological solutions if these solutions satisfy $p(t_0)=0$ for some $t_0$ in their domain (since the system is autonomous we can always shift $t_0$ to $0$).

> If I attempt to numerically integrate the equations of motion, the solver gives a solution for ψ with a discontinuous jump at the singularity, with ψ going from some value $−ψ_0$ to $ψ_0$.

I think it is just a problem of the solver. These configurations $(\pm 1, \psi_0)$ in the configuration space $(p,\psi)$ have nothing pathological from the geometric point of view. Just the curve $\psi=\psi(p)$ passes through $(\pm 1, \psi_0)$ and  has *vertical tangent*  there (parallel to $p = \pm 1$) since  $$\frac{d\psi}{dp} = \frac{\psi'}{p'} = - \frac{p}{\phi \sqrt{1-p^2} \sin \psi}\:,$$
unless the disaster happens exactly  at $(\pm 1, k\pi)$ requiring a more sophisticated analysis.